# Rudin's functional analysis, theorem 4.1.(completeness of $\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, proof-explanation, topological-vector-spaces

> Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are normed space. Associate to each $\Lambda \in \mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ the number
>   $$\lVert \Lambda \rVert = \sup \left\{ \lVert \Lambda x \rVert : x \in X, \lVert x \rVert \leq 1 \right\}.$$
>   This definition of $\lVert \Lambda \rVert$ makes $\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ into a normed space. If $Y$ is a Banach space, so is $\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$.

The proof that $\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ is fine and simple enough. I don't get a subtle step for proving the completeness.

> Assume now that $Y$ is complete and that $\left\{ \Lambda_n \right\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$. Since
>   $$
> \lVert \Lambda_n x - \Lambda_m x \rVert \leq \lVert \Lambda_n - \Lambda_m  \rVert \lVert x \rVert
> $$
>   and since it is assumed that $\lVert \Lambda_n - \Lambda_m  \rVert \to 0$ as $n$ and $m$ tend to $\infty$, $\left\{ \Lambda_n x \right\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $Y$ for every $x \in X$. Hence
>   $$
> \Lambda x = \lim_{n\to \infty} \Lambda_n x \;\;\;\; (4)
> $$
>   exists. Is is clear that $\Lambda : X \to Y$ is linear. If $\epsilon > 0$, the right side of (4) does not exceed $\epsilon \lVert x \rVert$, provided that $m$ and $n$ are sufficiently large.

And here is the very bit I don't get

> It follows that
>   $$
> \lVert \Lambda x - \Lambda_m x \rVert \leq \epsilon \lVert x \rVert
> $$
>   for all large $m$.

Could you please explain this bit?

Also to me (4) is actually what we want to prove, to me it is obvious there's a $y \in Y$ such that

$$
y = \lim_{n \to \infty} \Lambda_n x
$$

but we should prove that there's $\Lambda \in \mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ such that

$$
y = \Lambda x
$$

but the author seems to skip this, why can he skip it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note simply that for all $n,m$ and $x$,
$$\|\Lambda x-\Lambda_m x\|\leq\|\Lambda x-\Lambda_nx\|+\|\Lambda_n x-\Lambda_m x\|\quad (*)$$
Let $\epsilon>0$. By (4), there exists $N_0$ such that for all $n>N_0$, the middle term is smaller than $\epsilon\| x\|/2$. Since $\{\Lambda_n\}$ is Cauchy, there exists $N_1$ such that if $n,m > N_1$, then $\|\Lambda_n-\Lambda_n\|<\epsilon/2$. Now let $m>N_1$. Choose $n>\max\{N_0,N_1\}$. Then by (*):
$$\|\Lambda x-\Lambda_m x\|\leq\epsilon\|x\|/2+\|\Lambda_nx-\Lambda_mx\|<\epsilon\|x\|/2+\epsilon\|x\|/2=\epsilon\|x\|$$

**Added after answer was accepted**

Actually the reason is much simpler. By (4) $\Lambda_nx$ tends to $\Lambda x$, so given $\epsilon>0$ there is $N$ such that if $n>N$, we have $\|\Lambda_nx-\Lambda x\|<\epsilon\|x\|$, where $\epsilon\|x\|$ "plays the role" of $\epsilon$. Now just replace $n$ by $m$.

Comment: Please... derive the inequality. Because to me from what you wrote it follows $$\|\Lambda x-\Lambda_m x\|\leq\|\Lambda x-\Lambda_nx\|+\epsilon \| x \|, $$ for $m, n$ sufficiently large

Comment: There is nothing to derive. It is an immediate consequence of the triangle inequality:
$\Lambda x-\Lambda_mx=(\Lambda x-\Lambda_n x)+(\Lambda_nx-\Lambda_m x)$.

Comment: I meant how does $$ \lVert \Lambda x - \Lambda_m x \rVert \leq \epsilon \lVert x \rVert$$ follows from $$\|\Lambda x-\Lambda_m x\|\leq\|\Lambda x-\Lambda_nx\|+\|\Lambda_n x-\Lambda_m x\|$$

Comment: Does it follow from both the bound on $\| \Lambda_n x - \Lambda_m x\|$ and $\| \Lambda x - \Lambda_n x\| \to 0$ because of the limit?

Comment: @user8469759 (4) implies that there is $N$ such that $\|\Lambda_nx - \Lambda_mx\|\le (\epsilon/2)\|x\|$ for all $x\in X$ and $n,m>N$. (5) implies that for each $x\in X$ there is $N_x$ such that $\|\Lambda x - \Lambda_n x\|\le (\epsilon/2)\|x\|$ if $n>N_x$. Thus, $\|\Lambda x - \Lambda_m x\|\le \|\Lambda x - \Lambda_nx\| + \|\Lambda_nx - \Lambda_mx\|\le \epsilon\|x\|$ for all $x\in X$, $m>N$, and $n>\max\{N,N_x\}$.